# Add type='tel' attribute to webform field

Tags: webforms

I want to add the html5 tel attribute to a particular field in my webform form in order to prompt mobile devices to display the appropriate keyboard.

I was trying this:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

    /* add html5 phone type for phones and smarter devices to use */
    /* usage: just include the word 'phone' in the field title and have the field of type 'textfield' */

    foreach ($form['submitted'] as &$field){
        if (is_array($field) && isset($field['#title']) && stristr(strtolower($field['#title']), 'phone') && isset($field['#type']) && ($field['#type'] == 'textfield')){
            $field['#attributes']['type'] = 'tel';
        }
    }
}
```

but the attribute doesn't get applied and the resulting field has the type of "text"

I suspect there may be a hook for webforms that will let me adjust the output, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal 7 core field [doesn't support](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) HTML 5 form elements.

You should try the [Elements](http://drupal.org/project/elements) module to do that.

> This module intends to become a repository for advanced form elements. Supports HTML 5 standards like: (url, email, search, tel, number, range)